# Trouble finding a regular expression with lookahead/ lookbehind funcftion

Tags: python, regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds

I've been having an issue with getting my regular expression right. I'm looking to get just specific numbers in the following strings. For example, the following are some strings along with the regular expression I'm using

```
matcher = re.compile(r'(?<=[/\- ])([0-9]+)')
string = 'Redundant 100/70/50/50-0/0/0/0; EX-SEP ANN IMPLANT MAX.                     '
string2 = 'Big High 200/40/40/0/0-80/60/40/0/0; EX-WP 9months 7.                                                                                                                                                                                                 '
```

The outcome from this is

```
['100', '100', '85', '50', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['100', '80', '50', '0', '0', '80', '60', '40', '0', '0', '9', '7']
```

I'd like to figure out a way to get only the numbers next to a '/' but not the '9' and '7' in the second string for instance. I can't find a way to do this and have tried using a lookbehind expression but can't get just the numbers I want without also retrieving other numbers in my strings.

This is all new to me and I'd really appreciate any help on why I'm not getting my expected answers for each string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match digit sequences close to `/` or `-` using

```
(?<=[/-])[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=[/-])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W8NKxT/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

*Details*

- `(?<=[/-])[0-9]+` - one or more digits that have a `/` or `-` in front
- `|` - or
- `[0-9]+(?=[/-])` - one or more digits that have a `/` or `-` right after.

Comment: Thanks! I've been stuck on this for a while and figured there was a simpler solution than what I was thinking of doing

Comment: If anything is unclear, or the answer is not meeting the OP requirements, just let me know so that I could fix the solution.

Comment: Everything works great! Thanks, that's a big help with my confusion around this topic